# Swap raster pixel values in with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I have a raster with one band and pixel values 0 and 1 (palletted symbology), which I simply want to swap.
I have done it as follows in the GUI. How could I translate this to PyQGIS (and I guess there is a simpler way?)

QGIS Raster Calculator:
`if(raster@1 = 0, 1, 0)`

The result has singleband gray as symbology, so I need to classify to get to unique values again, which seems to be very expensive. Also, a NoData value of 3.4e+38 is added (I need 1 to be NoData).

Comment: You can use the processing alg Python code : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#raster-calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by J.Monticolo, I used `processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator",{'INPUT_A': pfad, 'BAND_A': 1, 'FORMULA': '(A==0)', 'RTYPE':0, 'NO_DATA':1,'OUTPUT': r"D:\QGIS\raster.tif"})`

About the expression ('FORMULA'):
When the pixel value is 0 it gets changed to the result of the logical test, which is true and therefore 1, when it's 1 it's false => 0.
I understand now that the symbology (single band/palette) is just a cosmetique issue, so I did not change that :)